# JS - beginner - function isMaleName()

Tags: javascript, function

In polish language most of the female name end in letter "a", which help to quickly identify the gender. Except is "Bonawentura" which is male name.

I need to write function which will tell:

- if male name - true
- if female name - false
- if "Bonawentura" - true

This is what I did:
example 1:

```
function isMaleName(name) {
  let pieces = name.split("");
  let last = pieces[pieces.length - 1];
  if ((name = "bonawentura")) {
    return true;
  } else if ((last = "a")) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

2 conditions complete:

- if male name - true
- if "Bonawentura" - true

example 2:

```
function isMaleName(name) {
  let pieces = name.split("");
  let last = pieces[pieces.length - 1];
  if ((last = "a")) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

1 condition complete:

- if female name - false

Comment: These are assignments, not equality checks

Comment: I guess this a probably a learning assignment, but `return name === 'bonawentura' || 'a' !== name[name.length - 1];` will do. Dissecting it, will maybe give you new insights.

Comment: yes @Yoshi, you are right. This is learning assignment.

Comment: @thinkgruen is saying that you are using the assignment symbol `=` instead of the equality checks `===`

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a Value instead of checking it. 
You should use `name == "bonawentura"` instead of `name = "bonawentura"`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function isMaleName(name) {
    let pieces = name.split("");
    let last = pieces[pieces.length - 1];
    if (name === "bonawentura") {
      return true;
    } else if (last === "a") {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I think it should be look like this, use two or three `=`  instead of using one  `=`.

Comment: thank you, 
Ok, right now is working. But one thing. "bonawentura" = false "boNAweNtura" = false What I can do to change this and every time when I write "Bonawentura" it will tell true.

Comment: just change `if (name === "bonawentura") ` to `if (name.toLowerCase() === "bonawentura")`, it should be working

Comment: It works, but still soooo much code, for something that can be done in one line (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one line, and support lowercase/uppercase/boNAweNtura :

```js
const isMaleName = name => !name.endsWith("a") || name.toLowerCase()==="bonawentura";

console.log(isMaleName("Joe")) // true
console.log(isMaleName("Lena")) // false
console.log(isMaleName("boNAweNtura")) // true
console.log(isMaleName("David")) // true
console.log(isMaleName("Sara")) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

My comment above was maybe a bit misleading. So here in full:

```
function isMaleName(name) {
  // convert input to lowercase
  name = name.toLowerCase();

  // check if it's the fixed string 'bonawentura'
  return name === 'bonawentura'
      // if not, check if it not ends with an 'a'.
      || 'a' !== name[name.length - 1];
}
```

Refs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#character_access
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase